# Convert integer to string for linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, typeconverter

Sorry for the vague information. Here is what I am trying. I am trying to create a method that takes my object LString and converts the integer argument into an object LString. This is using Linked lists. I have a Node class which constructs and initializes nodes. This is the last method for me to complete on a project.

I am confused on how to go about it however. I have been creating a string class using linked lists and nodes. How do I convert this integer argument into my object type of LString?

Here are parts of my LString class that seem relevant to the question:

```
public class LString{

   private Node front ;  //first val in list    *******CHANGED
   private Node back;   //last val in list
   private int size = 0;
   private int i;
   private int offset;

   public LString(){
      //construct empty list
      Node LString = new Node();
      front = null;

   }

   //return value of specified index
   public char charAt(int index){
      Node current = front;
      for(int i = 0; 0 < index; i++){
         current = current.next;
      }
      return current.data;

   }

   //return number of chars of lstring
   public int length(){
      int count = 0;
      Node current = front;
      while(current != null){
         current = current.next;
         count++;
      }
      return count++;

   }

   public String toString(){
      if(front == null){
         return "[]";
      } else {
         String result = "[" + front.data;
         Node current = front.next;
         while(current != null){
            result += current.data; //might need to add ", page 967
            current = current.next;
         }
         result += "]";
         return result;
      }   
   }
```

//***********My attempt although it is very wrong********

```
   public static LString valueOf(int i){
    int c;
    char m;
    LString ans = new LString(); 
    Node current = new Node();
    // convert the String to int
    for(int w = i;w < i; w++) {
        c = i % 10;
        i = i / 10;
        m = (char) ('0' + c);
    }
    return ans;           
}
```

My Node class:

```
public class Node{
   public char data;
   public Node next;

   //constructors from page 956
   public Node()
   {
      this('\0',null);  //'\0' is null char for java
   }

   public Node(char initialData, Node initialNext)
   {
      data = initialData;
      next = initialNext;
   }

   public void addNodeAfter(char element)   
   {
      next = new Node(element, next);
   }

   public char getData()
   {
      return data;
   }

   public Node getNext(){  
      return next;   
   }

   public void setNext(Node n){
      next = n;
   }

   public void setData(char d){
      data = d;
   }
}
```

Comment: The question as asked does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a `LinkedList<int>` because the generic types cannot be primitives, but having said that, it's easy to add Integers to a LinkedList and no need to "convert" them to String.

i.e., use a `LinkedList<Integer>`.

Otherwise if this doesn't answer your question, then please tell us more about the actual problem and less about your proposed code solution. I suspect that your question is really an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in disguise.

Comment: for each value, you can use toString() method to convert it into String.

Comment: @RahulKumar: but why? What's the indication for this? The original question as asked is too vague and overly broad to answer this just yet.

Comment: i thought because he asked for converting LL of integer to String.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using iteration.
Then use `Integer.toString` method to convert each element from Integer to String.

```
LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
for(LinkedList<Integer> item : integers ){
   strings.add(Integer.toString(item));
}
```

This will work for you.